# chained Multi select box in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for my development. I have a view which consists of 5 multiple select box, in which initially the default data will be populated while the page is loading. It should be chained selected i.e based on the first multi box changes the data should change for the remaining 4 select boxes, second box's changes will be reflected in the remaining three and so on.

please can you help me to obtain the chained selections for all the five boxes in which the data will be populated from model via controller.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that you can't do that with CodeIgniter alone. The good news is that there are [plenty](http://www.mrforbes.com/blog/2009/01/a-quick-code-igniter-and-jquery-ajax-tutorial/) [of](http://choosedaily.com/1052/9-ways-to-integrate-ajax-with-codeigniter/) [tutorials](http://littlebrain.org/2008/05/27/codeigniter-and-ajax-using-jquery-tutorial/) which can help you with that.

The problem is that CodeIgniter is a back-end framework. Its job: return values to HTTP request. It can't modify or update anything once it's sent. It is very good at that, but it can't actually modify anything once it's in the browser. To do that you need a front-end tool like JavaScript which will interpret the data sent by CodeIgniter and display the data based on what was already sent.

Comment: Ya i can do with jquery combined with codeigniter please suggest me a jquery library or plugin if available. which will help me to chain select all the 5 multi select boxes.